# Is there a "windows" approach to solve a STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION error?

Tags: windows, windows-10, azure, application-launch, segmentation-fault

Good evening and thank you in advance, here is the challenge I'm facing.

I have a .exe file I need to run from my Windows 10 Pro computer. Once I open it, it crashes after ~10 seconds. When I check the file logs, I get an error code of 3221225477.

To the best of my knowledge, in Windows OS, such a code number is associated with Segmentation Faults and a STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION error. Also from what I've investigated so far, in the C and C++ programming languages, such errors are raised when the pointer attempts to access part of the memory that doesn't exists or isn't allowed to access.

My computer is quite recent and never gave me problems. I have a far older laptop that can barely run Windows 10, yet succeeds in running the .exe file.

That made me question whether it was a bug associated with the software and not something associated with my computer, such as a firewall or antivirus-related problem.

If you guys could give me hints or paths to fix my issue...

Here are my log files when I try to run the software:

```
[2021-12-18 22:08:03.747] [info] [OnVUE] [SecureBrowserService] Windows Secure Browser download finished, attempts=1, fileSize=3.648032, machine_id="e950a8af-54fd-47fc-905f-bff18b1b7a94"
[2021-12-18 22:08:48.186] [info] [OnVUE] Launching ITS Secure Browser: appPath=C:\Users\Guillaume\AppData\Roaming\OnVUE\TestTakerSBBrowser.exe, params=/urlhttps://candidatelaunchst.onvue.com/delivery?session_id=12091700&access_code=685298183&locale=en-US&token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InZiOW5lSjB6ZVkyeXU3N1V3elpOb2w3YXhwTTcwOXR2eGQweFZ1TW5Hb0UifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJPblZVRSIsImlhdCI6MTYzOTg4MzE1MSwianRpIjoiMWUzZmQ5OGItYTY1NS00MDdhLTkwZTgtNmE0YjZiOWQwYjdmIiwic3ViIjo2ODUyOTgxODMsIm1pZCI6ImU5NTBhOGFmLTU0ZmQtNDdmYy05MDVmLWJmZjE4YjFiN2E5NCIsImV4cCI6MTYzOTg5MDM1MSwib3BTZXNzaW9uIjp7ImFpT3B0T3V0Ijp0cnVlfX0.0txQCh68ZG4r6U63ulG6VQ-RXTB11w03MiHjJGcFNFc,/Institutioncodesystem_test, machine_id="e950a8af-54fd-47fc-905f-bff18b1b7a94"
[2021-12-18 22:08:53.206] [info] [OnVUE] The browser process is being asked to exit: os="win", browser="secure_browser", code=3221225477, machine_id="e950a8af-54fd-47fc-905f-bff18b1b7a94"
[2021-12-18 22:08:53.208] [info] [OnVUE] Handling SecureBrowser exit: code=3221225477, proctorIsRevoking="false",
     proctorIsRestarting="false, connectionLossRestarting="false", machine_id="e950a8af-54fd-47fc-905f-bff18b1b7a94"
[2021-12-18 22:08:53.211] [info] [OnVUE] Default SecureBrowser exit: code=3221225477, machine_id="e950a8af-54fd-47fc-905f-bff18b1b7a94"
[2021-12-18 22:08:53.262] [info] [OnVUE] Handling exit for SecureBrowser Windows: code=3221225477, message="undefined", machine_id="e950a8af-54fd-47fc-905f-bff18b1b7a94"
[2021-12-18 22:08:53.282] [info] [OnVUE] Secured browser shutdown: exitCode=3221225477, message=SecureBrowser unknown shutdown, routingEvent=/system-test-launchtransferredToProctor=false, proctorStarted=false, machine_id="e950a8af-54fd-47fc-905f-bff18b1b7a94"
```

Thank you all for your help, it really bothers me

Comment: In *Settings* type *Problem Reports* and post the detail of your error.

Comment: Two things I do is 1) Enable "Failure" security audit event logging; and 2) Run Process Monitor (ProcMon), filter on your process name, start the capture, re-run your .exe, wait for it to terminate, stop the ProcMon capture, then search ProcMon output for "DENIED".  [This article](http://improve.dk/solving-access-denied-errors-using-process-monitor/) should help.  In most cases, it's just a simple matter of file, folder, or registry permissions that need tweaking.

Comment: @user1644677 sorry for the late awnser. I opened Problem Reports yet no problem gets reported. The list simply sits empty. Idk why.

Comment: @leeharvey1 sorry for the late awnser. Process Monitor was very useful and intuitive. Thanks for sharing. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be associated with "denied access". Nothing actually seems to be out of the ordinary. I try to find the "anterior" step that caused the crash, but all I find is the program getting called, then process be created with the detail: PID: 1212, Command Line: C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WerFault.exe -u -p 10768 -s 1564

This is were my current investigation stalls right now

Comment: WerFault (Window error reporting) is the program that collects info to write Problem Reports. The reports are accessed from two pages in Settings. Problem Reports and also Reliability Monitor.